# Reading bits from file

Tags: c++, byte, bit

I can read for example , 4 bytes from file using

```
ifstream r(filename , ios::binary | ios::in)
uint_32 readHere;
r.read( (char*)&readHere, 4 )
```

But how could i read 4.5 bytes = 4bytes and 4 bits.

What came to my mind is

```
ifstream r(filename , ios::binary | std::in)
uint_64t readHere;
r.read( (char*)&readHere, 5 ) // reading 5 bytes ;

uint_64t tmp = readHere & 11111111 // extract 5th bytes
tmp = tmp >> 4  // get first half of the bites
readHere = (( readHere >> 8 ) << 8) | tmp     // remove 5th byte then add 4 bits
```

But im not sure how shouldi take half of byte , if first or last 4.
Is there some better way how to retrieve it?

Comment: It's entirely to you to decide which bits in a byte come first.

Comment: You're going to need to declare `readHere` as a `uint64_t` (or something larger) in order to store 5 bytes in it.

Comment: yea , forgot about it , thanks i will fix it.

Comment: I was about to answer, and then realised how unclear the problem specification is.  What does this value represent?  Are there many of these packed together?  What is the endianness?  One thing I'm certain of is you should not read directly into an integer.  Read into a `char` array and then construct an integer by shifting the bytes.  Otherwise your underlying endianness will get in the way of whatever data representation you are trying to process.

Comment: i am running little endian , i do not test it on big endian yet. The value represent a bytes inside a file. All bytes are packed together.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit that you can read or write be it in file, or in memory is a char (a byte on common systems (*)).  You can browse longer element byte wise, and effectively endianness matters here.

```
uint32_t u = 0xaabbccdd;
char *p = static_cast<char *>(&u);
char c = p[0];    // c is 0xdd on a little endian system and 0xaa on a big endian one
```

But as soon as you are *inside* a byte all you can do is to use bitwise ands and shifts to extract the low order or high order bits. There is no longer endianness here except if **you** decide to use one convention.

BTW, if you read on a network interface or even on a serial line where bits are individually transfered, you get one full byte at a time, and there is no way to read only 4 bits on one read and the 4 others on next one.

(*) older systems (CDC in the 80's) used to have 6bits per character - but C++ did not exist at that time and I'm unsure whether C compilers existed there

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear whether this is a file format that *you control*, or if it's something else.  Anyway, let's assume you have some integer data type that can hold a 36-bit unsigned value:

```
typedef uint64_t u36;
```

Now, regardless of whether your system uses big-endian or little-endian, you can write the value to a binary stream in a predictable order by doing them one byte at a time.  Let's use big-endian, because it's slightly easier to picture the bits assembling together to create a value.

You can just use naive shifting and masking into a small buffer.  The only thing to decide is where to truncate the half-byte.  But if you follow the pattern of shifting each value by another 8 bits, then the remainder naturally falls in the high-order.

```
ostream & write_u36( ostream & s, u36 val )
{
    char bytes[5] = {
        (val >> 28) & 0xff,
        (val >> 20) & 0xff,
        (val >> 12) & 0xff,
        (val >> 4 ) & 0xff,
        (val << 4 ) & 0xf0
    };
    return s.write( bytes, 5 );
}
```

But this isn't how you'd actually write a bunch of these numbers.  You'd have to hold off the 5th byte until you were finished or you could pack the next value into it.  Or you would always write two values at a time:

```
ostream & write_u36_pair( ostream & s, u36 a, u36 b )
{
    char bytes[9] = {
        (a >> 28) & 0xff,
        (a >> 20) & 0xff,
        (a >> 12) & 0xff,
        (a >> 4 ) & 0xff,
        (a << 4 ) & 0xf0 | (b >> 32) & 0x0f,
        (b >> 24) & 0xff,
        (b >> 16) & 0xff,
        (b >> 8) & 0xff,
        b & 0xff
    };
    return s.write( bytes, 9 );
}
```

---

And so now, you might see how to go about **reading** values and deserialising them back into integers.  The simplest way is to read two at a time.

```
istream & read_u36_pair( istream & s, u36 & a, u36 & b )
{
    char bytes[9];
    if( s.read( bytes, 9 ) )
    {
        a = (u36)bytes[0] << 28
          | (u36)bytes[1] << 20
          | (u36)bytes[2] << 12
          | (u36)bytes[3] << 4
          | (u36)bytes[4] >> 4;

        b = ((u36)bytes[4] & 0x0f) << 32
          | (u36)bytes[5] << 24
          | (u36)bytes[6] << 16
          | (u36)bytes[7] << 8
          | (u36)bytes[8];
    }
    return s;
}
```

If you wanted to read them one at a time, you'd need to keep track of some state so you knew how many bytes to read (either 5 or 4), and which shift operations to apply.  Something naive like this:

```
struct u36deser {
    char bytes[5];
    int which = 0;
};

istream & read_u36( istream & s, u36deser & state, u36 & val )
{
    if( state.which == 0 && s.read( state.bytes, 5 ) )
    {
        val = (u36)state.bytes[0] << 28
            | (u36)state.bytes[1] << 20
            | (u36)state.bytes[2] << 12
            | (u36)state.bytes[3] << 4
            | (u36)state.bytes[4] >> 4;
         state.which = 1;
    }
    else if( state.which == 1 && s.read( state.bytes, 4 ) )
    {
        val = ((u36)state.bytes[4] & 0x0f) << 32  // byte left over from previous call
            | (u36)state.bytes[0] << 24
            | (u36)state.bytes[1] << 16
            | (u36)state.bytes[2] << 8
            | (u36)state.bytes[3];
        state.which = 0;
    }
    return s;
}
```

All of this is purely hypothetical, which seems to be the point of your question anyway.  There are many other ways to serialise bits, and some of them are not at all obvious.